# 7zip - powershell exclude files/folders with variable

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm trying to zip a folder but exclude multiple directories using powershell.

I got the following:

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"  

$Source = "D:\Zip\*"
$Target = "D:\backup.7z"
$exclude = 'Customer\Images\*'

sz a -xr!'$Customer\Images\*' $Target $Source
```

This works fine.. But when I want the change the `-xr!` to `-xr!'$exclude'` or `-xr!$exclude` it stops working for some reason. Does the variable assigned above not get parsed?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded in single quoted strings.

Comment: It's not working in `-xr!$exclude` either..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
if (-not (Test-Path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
$7ZipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"  

$Source = "D:\Zip\*"
$Target = "D:\backup.7z"
$foldersToExclude = 'folder1', 'folder2'

$7zipParams = @('a',$Target)
@($foldersToExclude) | ForEach-Object { $7zipParams += "`"-xr!$_`"" }
$7zipParams += $Source

Write-Host ($7ZipPath+' '+$7zipParams -join ' ') # debug - show the command line
&$7ZipPath $7zipParams
```

We create an array of params to pass into 7zip, including the excluded folders. As we're appending the excluded folders, we prepend the folder names with the `-xr!` flags and wrap these in double qoutes.

The `#debug` line outputs the resultant command line to the console

I call 7zip slightly differently to you, by creating a string with the 7zip executable, then prepending the call to that string path with an ampersand.

This method can exclude multiple folders from the final archive, including `folder\subfolder` structure.

Comment: Thanks for the extended version! My next step was to use multiple exclude folders. But it seems you red my mind. I'll mark it as awnser

Comment: You're welcome. It took a few minutes to get the syntax correct!

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Use the variable inside double quotes if you want it to be expanded:`sz a "-xr!$exclude" $Target $Source`
2. Using the pattern `Customer\Images\*` excludes all files in the directory `Images`, but includes an empty directory in the resulting file. Use `Customer\Images` if you don't want to include the directory (or any of its files).